# Jquery toggle slide using a rel

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm definitely not a jQuery expert, so having trouble getting this to work properly.

I want to use a link, with rel="X" to slide toggle open/closed a div with class="X".

Default should be closed (or display:none;)

I'd also like to change the background image depending on whether or not the div is open or closed....thinking of maybe switching the link classname??

Trying a whole bunch of jQuery examples and just getting frustrated:(

Here's what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/4gn5G/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel]").click(function () {
        $(".[rel]").toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Comment: you forgot to include jquery in your fiddle. that's why its not working. Check my answer on how to automate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gn5G/3/),

you forgot to include jQuery in the page. Once you add that, the script will run fine.

If you want to automate that for all click events with rel, then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel]").click(function () {
        var divClass= $(this).attr('rel');
        $("." + divClass).toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4gn5G/6/)**

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I needed! Two questions: 1. how do I switch the class of the link from open to close? 2. can I make the toggle only slide from left to right, rather than for 0,0 to x,y?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the content of the attribute by which you selected, that you want to use, in your class-selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel]").click(function () {
        $("." + this.rel).toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel]").click(function () {
        $("." + this.getAttribute('rel')).toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

As you wrote it, you were simply selecting elements that had a class of `[rel]`, which would be none (since `[` and `]` are invalid characters for `id` and `class`).

Answer (score 0):

update to this:

```
$("a[rel]").click(function () {
    var cls = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("."+cls).toggle("slide");
});
```